# Scala invert zip

Tags: list, scala, functional-programming, tuples

I'd like to build the following list of tuples:

```
List(("a", 1), ("a", 2), ("a", 3), ("a", 4))
```

from two components:

1. `"a"`
2. `List(1,2,3,4)`

---

Known workarounds include:

```
List(1,2,3,4) zip Stream.continually("a") map { _.swap }

List(1,2,3,4).zipAll("a", "for missing values", "a")

List(1,2,3,4).map(("a",_))
```

---

However, I believe there is a better solution than these workarounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's your definition of "better"?
Here is some possible solution:

```
scala> (List.fill(4)("a"), List(1, 2, 3, 4)).invert
res0: List[(String, Int)] = List((a,1), (a,2), (a,3), (a,4))

scala> List(1, 2, 3, 4).map{ ("a", _) }
res1: List[(String, Int)] = List((a,1), (a,2), (a,3), (a,4))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just tried on a Scala worksheet:

```
List(1,2,3,4) map (v => ("a", v))         //> res0: List[(String, Int)] = List((a,1), (a,2), (a,3), (a,4))
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Nothing, I wonder if there's any other solution. I'm going to make permutation in the next step so I just wanted to use some zip here.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no direct implementation of an inverted zip method in the standard Scala collection library.

However, if you take a look at the [implementation of zip](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.4/src/library/scala/collection/IterableLike.scala#L242), which `List` takes from `IterableLike`, you can easily define your own `zipInvert` extension method:

```
import language.higherKinds

import collection.GenIterable
import collection.generic.CanBuildFrom

implicit class ZipInvert[A,CC[X] <: GenIterable[X]](coll: CC[A]) {
  def zipInvert[A1 >: A, B, That](that: GenIterable[B])(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[CC[A], (B, A1), That]): That = {
    val b = bf(coll)
    val these = coll.iterator
    val those = that.iterator
    while (these.hasNext && those.hasNext)
      b += ((those.next, these.next))
    b.result
  }
}

val numberList = List.range(1,5)

numberList zipInvert Stream.continually("a")
```

Paste this into the REPL to execute it or paste it in a file and execute it with `scala -i`:

```
scala -i ZipInvert.scala
Loading ZipInvert.scala...
import language.higherKinds
import collection.GenIterable
import collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
defined class ZipInvert
numberList: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
res0: List[(String, Int)] = List((a,1), (a,2), (a,3), (a,4))
...
```

The example above is compiled with Scala 2.10.4.

If you want to have no intermediate collection at all, e.g. to avoid further memory overhead, use the `List` companion object:

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.4 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_51).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> List.tabulate(4)(index => ("a",index+1))
res0: List[(String, Int)] = List((a,1), (a,2), (a,3), (a,4))

scala>
```